# Find overlaping area of two images and merge them together with python

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have two images e.g. two screenshots of a web page. The end of one image is the same as the beginning of the second image.

How can I use python to find due overlap and merge the two images accordingly?

Unfortunately my idea does not work.

1. load images with pillow
2. convert to grayscale
3. convert to numpy array
4. check lines for equality

Unfortunately no equal lines are found.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Kindly add representative sample images. Thank you.

Comment: you can try the [stitching](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching) package

Answer (score 1):

This code finds the overlap between two images and blend them together.
code repo : https://github.com/linrl3/Image-Stitching-OpenCV

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys

class Image_Stitching():
    def __init__(self) :
        self.ratio=0.85
        self.min_match=10
        self.sift=cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
        self.smoothing_window_size=800

    def registration(self,img1,img2):
        kp1, des1 = self.sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
        kp2, des2 = self.sift.detectAndCompute(img2, None)
        matcher = cv2.BFMatcher()
        raw_matches = matcher.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)
        good_points = []
        good_matches=[]
        for m1, m2 in raw_matches:
            if m1.distance < self.ratio * m2.distance:
                good_points.append((m1.trainIdx, m1.queryIdx))
                good_matches.append([m1])
        img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good_matches, None, flags=2)
        cv2.imwrite('matching.jpg', img3)
        if len(good_points) > self.min_match:
            image1_kp = np.float32(
                [kp1[i].pt for (_, i) in good_points])
            image2_kp = np.float32(
                [kp2[i].pt for (i, _) in good_points])
            H, status = cv2.findHomography(image2_kp, image1_kp, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
        return H

    def create_mask(self,img1,img2,version):
        height_img1 = img1.shape[0]
        width_img1 = img1.shape[1]
        width_img2 = img2.shape[1]
        height_panorama = height_img1
        width_panorama = width_img1 +width_img2
        offset = int(self.smoothing_window_size / 2)
        barrier = img1.shape[1] - int(self.smoothing_window_size / 2)
        mask = np.zeros((height_panorama, width_panorama))
        if version== 'left_image':
            mask[:, barrier - offset:barrier + offset ] = np.tile(np.linspace(1, 0, 2 * offset ).T, (height_panorama, 1))
            mask[:, :barrier - offset] = 1
        else:
            mask[:, barrier - offset :barrier + offset ] = np.tile(np.linspace(0, 1, 2 * offset ).T, (height_panorama, 1))
            mask[:, barrier + offset:] = 1
        return cv2.merge([mask, mask, mask])

    def blending(self,img1,img2):
        H = self.registration(img1,img2)
        height_img1 = img1.shape[0]
        width_img1 = img1.shape[1]
        width_img2 = img2.shape[1]
        height_panorama = height_img1
        width_panorama = width_img1 +width_img2

        panorama1 = np.zeros((height_panorama, width_panorama, 3))
        mask1 = self.create_mask(img1,img2,version='left_image')
        panorama1[0:img1.shape[0], 0:img1.shape[1], :] = img1
        panorama1 *= mask1
        mask2 = self.create_mask(img1,img2,version='right_image')
        panorama2 = cv2.warpPerspective(img2, H, (width_panorama, height_panorama))*mask2
        result=panorama1+panorama2

        rows, cols = np.where(result[:, :, 0] != 0)
        min_row, max_row = min(rows), max(rows) + 1
        min_col, max_col = min(cols), max(cols) + 1
        final_result = result[min_row:max_row, min_col:max_col, :]
        return final_result
img1 = cv2.imread('image1.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('image2.jpg')
final=Image_Stitching().blending(img1,img2)
cv2.imwrite('panorama.jpg', final)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `cvtColor` function in the `cv2` library to convert to grayscale, then compute MSE (Mean Square Error) between two images using `numpy` like so:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load the input images
img1 = cv2.imread("path/to/img1.png")
img2 = cv2.imread("path/to/img2.png")

# convert the images to grayscale
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# define the function to compute MSE between two images
def mse(img1, img2):
    h, w = img1.shape
    diff = cv2.subtract(img1, img2)
    err = np.sum(diff**2)
    mse = err/(float(h*w))
    return mse, diff

error, diff = mse(img1, img2)
print("Image matching Error between the two images:",error)
cv2.imshow("difference", diff)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I have tried your code and tried to understand it. How do I find the area where the two images are the same?

Comment: When cv2.imshow() presents the final image, the difference between the two images is shown in grey where no match is found. If the two images are identical, this code will essentially show you a black image.

Comment: OK. I think I understand my mistake. The code compares the lines of both images and finds nothing. In my case the last x lines of image 1 are equal to the first x lines of image 2. Question: What is the value of x and does a block exist where the images are equal?

Comment: Unless I'm misreading, this compares the two images pixel-by-pixel, as though they are two images of the same part of the same webpage. But they aren't — one is scrolled almost an entire y-height compared to the other: “The end of one image is the same as the beginning of the second image.”